# asp.net core 2 web api set hosting url from appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

On an asp.net core 2 web api, I want to be able to set the url on which my api will listen (api run as windows service) based on a value in appsettings.json file. I can't find a way to achive it, how can I have acces to an instance of `IConfiguration` ?

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls({value_from_appsettings})
    .Build()
    .RunAsService();
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#overriding-configuration) might be helpful. Ultimately, you have to create your own instance of `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to gain access to the configuration *before* you go down the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` path, you'll need to build your own `IConfiguration` instance using `ConfigurationBuilder`.

Taking the example from your question, you can use something like the following:

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

var appSettingsConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(pathToContentRoot)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls(appSettingsConfiguration["Your:Value"])
    .Build()
    .RunAsService();
```

This is somewhat explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#overriding-configuration) where the example uses instead a `hosting.json` file to set this up. It also makes use of `UseConfiguration`, which allows you to specify a value for e.g. `urls`, which will be picked up automatically.

Comment: I have a hard time to have access to environment name to add appSettings.{environment}.json file, how can I have access to it ?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437325/access-environment-name-in-program-main-in-asp-net-core) for inspiration. i.e. `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`

Comment: An alternative would be to do it the same way `WebHostBuilder` [does it](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L44), but that involves creating yet *another* `IConfiguration` first.