# Why doesn't environment variable reference work for MS Build Target?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, msbuild

I have the following configuration, but the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable doesn't make it to the CsProj config.

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
    // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
    // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Web",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Web/Web.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Web/Web.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Web/Web.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Web/Properties/launchSettings.json**

```json
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15269",
            "sslPort": 44386
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true
        },
        "Web": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
        }
    }
}
```

**Web/Web.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="PreCompile" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)/node_modules/.bin/gulp build --environment $(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

```js
// gulpFile.ts
export { default as build } from './build/Sass';

// build/Sass.ts
import type { TaskFunction } from 'gulp';
import { dest, src } from 'gulp';
import * as fiber from 'fibers';
import * as sass from 'gulp-dart-sass';


const environment = process.argv[3] === '--environment' ? process.argv[4] : 'Staging';


const task: TaskFunction = () => {

    console.log(`Hello!!!!! ${environment}`);

    console.log(process.env);

    return src('./Web/themes/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass({ fiber }))
        .pipe(dest('./Web/wwwroot/themes'));
};


export default task;
```

***Output***

```
 Executing task: dotnet build /.../Web/Web.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Web -> /.../Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.dll
  Web -> /.../Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.Views.dll
  [17:50:28] Requiring external module ts-node/register
  [17:50:28] Working directory changed to ~/...
  [17:50:30] Using gulpfile ~/.../gulpfile.ts
  [17:50:30] Starting 'build'...
  Hello!!!!! undefined
  {
    TERM_PROGRAM: 'vscode',
    TERM: 'xterm-256color',
    SHELL: '/bin/zsh',
    TMPDIR: '/var/folders/pf/rmb77nvd2t99vjmq9z1xc6100000gn/T/',
    TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '1.52.1',
    DOTNET_HOST_PATH: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet',
    ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'undefined',
    LC_ALL: 'en_US.UTF-8',
    DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_SESSIONID: 'f3d95a71-5185-4c74-b373-da49d9b6f174',
    USER: 'roydukkey',
    COMMAND_MODE: 'unix2003',
    MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly: 'true',
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JpMQQSNA9S/Listeners',
    __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: '0x1F5:0x0:0x0',
    PATH: '/usr/local/php5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands',
    __CFBundleIdentifier: 'com.microsoft.VSCode',
    PWD: '.../Web',
    LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
    MSBuildSDKsPath: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/Sdks',
    XPC_FLAGS: '0x0',
    XPC_SERVICE_NAME: '0',
    SHLVL: '1',
    HOME: '...',
    VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN: '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js',
    LOGNAME: 'roydukkey',
    VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE: '/var/folders/pf/rmb77nvd2t99vjmq9z1xc6100000gn/T/vscode-git-8f8e32c0ee.sock',
    GIT_ASKPASS: '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh',
    VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE: '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer)',
    COLORTERM: 'truecolor',
    MSBuildExtensionsPath: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/',
    _: '.../node_modules/.bin/gulp',
    INIT_CWD: '.../Web'
  }
  [17:50:30] Finished 'build' after 71 ms

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Using launch settings from '/.../Web/Properties/launchSettings.json' [Profile 'Web']...
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'.
Loaded '/.../Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/netstandard.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Collections.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.ComponentModel.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.IO.FileSystem.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Threading.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Linq.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Memory.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Threading.Thread.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Text.Json.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Net.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.ObjectModel.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.Loader.dll'.
Loaded '/.../Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.Views.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Security.Claims.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Linq.Expressions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Console.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Threading.Tasks.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Xml.XDocument.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Private.Xml.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/System.IO.Pipelines.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Private.Uri.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Collections.Specialized.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Formats.Asn1.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Net.Security.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Net.Sockets.dll'.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: /.../Web
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /.../Web
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll'.
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'.
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.1/System.Net.WebSockets.dll'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Change the `build` task inside `tasks.json` to

```json
         {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"development"
                }
            },
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Web/Web.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
```

#### Explanation

The environment variables (ENVs) set inside **Launch Targets** of `launch.json` are passed to `program` only, and not to any of the launch tasks.
i.e. those ENVs are passed to `${workspaceFolder}/Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Web.dll` only, and not to the `build` task inside `preLaunchTask`. 
FYI, building your project (**.csproj**) is being done by `dotnet build` & not `msbuild`, there are slight differences. 
Anyways, this build is initiated by the `preLaunchTask` (**build**). 
So if you want the ENVs to be passed to the project builder ( and in turn to the gulp program), then you need some way to pay those to the **build** task, specified in `tasks.json`
ENVs can be passed to the tasks via `options` property.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

And no... you can't reuse the ENV variable like this

```json
"env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"${env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}"
}
```

Reason is as specified above; that ENVs from **Launch Targets** are not passed to the tasks.

Comment: I just tried this, seems correct. Do you happen to why the process was designed this way? Seems like somethings missing, no?

Comment: I can speculate a reason, but no, I don't have any reputable source to back it up.
Most probable reason, is that the `launch.json` is specific to [omisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md)
While the [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) inside `tasks.json` are common to all, it is a feature of vscode itself.
So what you are essentially requesting, is passing an extension specific configuration to the host program itself, which I don't think is a valid flow; that basically creates an inverse dependency

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to move the environment variable from `env` in your `.vscode/launch.json` file to `environmentVariables` in the "Web" property in `Web/Properties/launchSettings.json`.

[learn.microsoft.com reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)

Comment: @roydukkey That's odd. I don't know Gulp well enough but are you certain that it's being called correctly from your Web.csproj file?

Comment: This what I've used to source my code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0#run-gulp-tasks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2019#to-use-an-environment-variable-in-an-msbuild-project

Answer (score 0):

I think try adding another args element containing "/p:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)" in your tasks.json invocations?

Looking at the output of process.env it looks as if the invocation environment of dotnet.exe isn't inheriting the environment variables from VSCode.

Comment: Didn't work. Tried `/p:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}` as per https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables. Didn't work either.

Comment: apologies for wrong syntax. The environment pipeline seems to be -
 
Code.exe -> dotnet.exe -> MSBuild.exe -> gulp

You've shown that gulp doesn't have the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set (process.env) - it seems that VSCode isn't supplying it into the environment of dotnet.exe. I would try setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in your shell then invoking dotnet.exe directly in that shell to verify, I suspect this will identify Code.exe as not supplying the env as it should.

Comment: That is sort of correct. Rather, I believe `dotnet.exe` is not passing the variable to `MSBuild.exe`, since the environment does change in the output, when changing the value in `launch.json`

> `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development`

Answer (score 0):

Despite passing the environment variable or not, it seems to me that you are trying to run the program in `Development` mode, right? You seem to be succeeding in doing that, since the hosting environment is shown in the last output window to be `Development` in fact. So, if this is your goal, perhaps it is solved *per si*.

On the other hand, you could find useful to define the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable for production uses. If this is the case, defining it in MSBuild may not be what you want, nor absolutely is defining in the *launchSettings.json*, since this is used only for development purposes. So, I think that defining it as environment variable in the environment you want to run the app would be a good option - then, whether the value is *Development*, *Staging* or *Production* is up to the deployment pipeline.

However, please note that, if you do not want to access the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable itself, you may actually do not need to define it. The default hosting environment of a published app is `Production`, and it only changes when the environment variable is provided ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment)).

This [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538919/asp-net-core-3-1-launchsettings-json-environment-variables-are-not-set-on-local) has pretty good information on this topic :)

Comment: I just want to be able to switch the whole stack from `'Development'` and `'Production'` in ONE location. Since `launch.json` is at the top of the stack, and since EnvVars are configurable there, I don't see why my expectation is unreasonable.

Comment: Ok, understood :) Well, that file is used only when running from VS Code, it is not used in any other situation; that kind of files is ignored when you publish the application. That's why I think it is better to handle the variable at the "machine" level. Also, that is only an environment variable that influences the host environment mode; however, you may change the environment mode without setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable (based on what you showed, I think that you are only verifying the environment mode, not the variable).

Comment: With this said, if you want to try to set the variable or the environment when performing `dotnet run`, you may follow the ansewrs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322565/dotnet-run-or-dotnet-watch-with-development-environment-from-command-line). If you only want to debug stuff on the run, in case you are in a Windows machine, you may want to try the Visual Studio IDE (Community edition is free) instead of the Code, since this becomes much easier